# What happens to a diode when it break-downs?

Tags: diodes, physics

What happens when you expose a diode beyond the break-down voltage, does it become conductive in both senses or non-conductive in both senses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At reverse breakdown voltage on a PN junction diode, you get a large increase in reverse current (normally close to zero) for a small further increase in voltage.

Breakdown is non destructive - provided thermal effects do not destroy the diode. Zener diodes are devices with specified low breakdown voltages that exploit this effect.

So for example a 10V 1W Zener could take 0.1A in reverse breakdown current continuously. If you exceed this thermal rating then the diode will be damaged in an unpredictable way.

Comment: Can you specify also the case when thermal effects do destroy the diode, what possibilities can this outcome have, is there a possibility that it becomes conductive in both senses ?

Comment: I can't specify it. It could become conductive in both directions, or become conductive in neither. Its not predictable - basically you have melted it!